# 64-bit long ints in Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android

I thought I read that in Java, all long ints were guaranteed to be 64-bit, even on a 32-bit machine.  But I could be wrong.  I have an Android app that runs on a tablet with a 32-bit ARM CPU.  My long ints behave like 32-bit ints (they overflow after they get to about 10^10).

Is this the correct behavior?

Is there a way to easily do 64-bit integers in Android apps?

========================== EDIT ===========================
I just looked at the code and started typing it in and realize the problem might be somewhere else.  I need to fix that bug, and verify the problem still occurs (which it probably won't) but I can't test it now because I don't have my Android device with me.  Hold off on this one until later.  Thanks for replying, but this is probably my dumb mistake.

Comment: post code.  I have never heard a Long referred to as a Long Integer.

Comment: Please show some code that exhibits the overflowing behavior.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't talking about C/C++? Java has always the same size for all data types. It absracts from the underlying architecture.

Comment: See above edits.  I think maybe the problem is elsewhere but I can't test the code for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Longs are 64 bits: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html Integers are 32 bits: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html